# Broken Image Link - Custom HTML module

Tags: joomla-3.x

I have created a default Custom HTML module, and put few thumbnail images and added hyperlinks. And when i see preview it show broken image link on few menus and some time it work perfectly. I checked both image urls from front-end.

Broken Image url: mysite.com/entertainment/images/geo_news.jpg

Working image url: mysite.com/images/geo_news.jpg

And my thumbnails are in /images/ directory

I just dont understand why on specific menu or browser it display broken link on few menu items? although it is working fine on other menus or on home page. I check backed and hyperlinks are fine. Even i cleared Joomla Cache but same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think my problem has been solved. Changed plugin order, and put System-SEF plugin before System-Cache. Broken image links are working now.

Answer (score 2):

Check that you are linking correctly to your images in the custom module. Note the difference between absolute and relative paths:

**Relative Path**
Relative paths can only be used when linking to content on the same domain. When using a relative path, the browser will look for the resource *relative* to the location of the link.

- If you add a `/` before the relative path, it will start from the root folder of your domain.
- If you don't include `/`, the path will be relative to your location. Usually this is the Joomla root directory.

**Absolute Path**
Absolute paths start with `http://` and is the full path to your image. In your case it should be: `http://YOURSITE.com/images/geo_news.jpg`. Test this URL in the browser bar, is should display your image.

Absolute paths is the safest solution, as it doesn't depend on what folder you're linking *from*, but you might get broken links if you change your domain name.

I suggest you try both options and see what works best for your setup:

```
<img src="http://YOURSITE.com/images/geo_news.jpg">
```

or

```
<img src="/images/geo_news.jpg">
```